# Swift: method to disable UITabBarItem not functioning

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbar, isenabled

I'm trying to disable a tab item if internet connection is not available. I have the following:

```
    internal func getViewControllers(connectionStatus: ConnectionService.ConnectionStatus) {
    if connectionStatus == .connected {
        if let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray,
            let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[1] as? UITabBarItem {
            print("***** \(arrayOfTabBarItems[1])")
            tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
        }
    } else {
           if let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray,
            let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[2] as? UITabBarItem {
            print("***** \(arrayOfTabBarItems[2])")
            tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

The method is called from another class which is detecting the connection status of the user's device. The method is called when it should be, but the tabBarItem is not disabled as I would expect.

The print statement is run and prints the following (when .connected):

```
***** <UITabBarItem: 0x11df3c8a0> title='Retrieve Completed Orders' image=<UIImage:0x2801bc090 named(main: tabbar_orders) {30, 30}>
```

Which is what I would expect. This is indeed the name of the second tab. Any ideas would be very much appreciated as this is driving me mad...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `isEnabled` property of tab bar items works to disable it. I believe `UITabBarItem` inherits that property from its parent class, `UIBarItem`.

Instead, you should implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)`

When the user taps on a tab bar item, the tab bar would call that method on its delegate. If you don't want the item to become active, you'd return false.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think something else is going on here though. No UI changes seem to be working. If I sub out the logic here for disabling the tab bar items and just try and change the tab bar text or anything, no UI changes are visible, even though the methods are clearly getting called